# Looking for examples of command chaining in Parsley 2.4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, parsley

In order to help me understand, I'm looking for examples of command chaining in Parsley. What I mean by command chaining is when one command returns a result that is then immediately used to initiate another command. I ask this question here because the parsley forums have been down for 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at the [Spicelib Task Framework](http://spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/2.4/manual/task.php#intro)? It should do everything you want to, and it has some good example.

Comment: I have tried it, but the examples are poor because there are no examples showing how to the Task Framework with the Parsley Framework. I keep getting "value is not a function" when I try using messaging and dynamic commands.

Comment: You might want to post your code about that so we can work it out :)